# Snowflake-How to filter out numbers whose digits are all the same?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, regexp-like

I am trying to filter out numbers whose all digits are the same- like '000000000','111111111111',etc..
I am hoping it could be done using REGEXP_LIKE in snowflake.
But it is not working.

These are the things I have tried to test:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[0-9]\\1+$') THEN '0'
    ELSE '1'
  END AS D;
```

tried adding more backslashes for escape sequence problem. Still didn't give me the desired output.

Comment: Is that a number or a string.  If a number you can use greater and less then.

Comment: Maybe `'^([0-9])\1+$'`? Or `'^([0-9])\\1+$'`?

Comment: How about `^([0-9])\\1+$`

Comment: The backreferences REGEXP are not supported: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp#using-backreferences

Comment: You could define a Javascript function, and use the backreference Regexp inside the Javascript also.

Comment: Not familiar with SQL and snowflake, but I think simply `^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+)$` should do the trick aswell, explicitly stating all 10 options of digits that could be repeated. See: https://regex101.com/r/Uh9Cn7/latest

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution not using ARRAY. This also only flags entries with repeating digits and ignores repeating non-digit characters. If you know the column will only have digits, the first condition of the WHEN can be omitted (see the commented line below).

```sql
with data as (
    select '1111111' num
    union 
    select '0000000' num
    union
    select '1234' num
    union
    select 'aaaa' num
)
select num
,case
    when (
        left(trim(num), 1) regexp '[0-9]'  -- Only needed if non-digits may be present
        and trim(num) = repeat(left(trim(num), 1),len(trim(num)))
    )  then '0'
    else '1'
 end AS d
from data;
```

| NUM | D |
| --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 0 |
| 0000000 | 0 |
| 1234 | 1 |
| aaaa | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Using a [Scalar JavaScript Function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-scalar-functions), we can access real regular expressions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uniform_digit_check(STR VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS $$
  return STR.match(/^(\d)\1+$/)?'0':'1';
  $$
  ;
```

we can then use like so:

```
select
    $1 as val
    ,uniform_digit_check(val)
from values
    ('111111'),
    ('111100'),
    ('0000000000'),
    ('abc');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with SQL and snowflake, but I think simply:

```
^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+)$
```

should do the trick aswell, explicitly stating all 10 options of digits that could be repeated.

See: regex101.com/r/Uh9Cn7/latest

---

Borrowing OPs SQL code, the solution could look like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+|0+)$') THEN '0'
    ELSE '1'
  END AS D;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with below solution, which would be more reliable and customizable

```
with data as (
select '1111111' num
union 
select '0000000' num
union
select '1234' num
)
select *
,case when array_size(ARRAY_DISTINCT(regexp_extract_all(num,'.'))) = 1 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS D
from data
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT column
FROM some_table
WHERE REPEAT (LEFT (column, 1), LENGTH (column)) = column -- same character repeated.
  AND LENGTH (column) > 1 -- more than one digit.
  AND columnt > 9 -- add this, only if column is int, and there sought to be more than one digits.
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[0-9]+$') -- add this, only if column is not int.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking [@DuesserBaest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13840270/duesserbaest)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78025248/9947159) just a little

```
select col, regexp_count(col,'^(0+|1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)$') as is_monodigit
from t
```